# How can i ignore @JsonIgnoreProperties in ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, objectmapper

I have following class in my Java application:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"myProperty"}, allowSetters = true)
public class Test {

    private String myProperty;

// getter and setter 
}
```

I want convert this object to json with ObjectMapper, but 'myProperty' does not convert and i want ignore that annotation(@JsonIgnoreProperties) but remember that i want still use another annotation.
before ask question i try fix it and define kind of custom Introspector and setAnnotationIntrospector to my object mapper separately and test it but problem not resolve:

```
public class TestCustomIntrospector1 extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        if (a.getAnnotated().equals(JsonIgnoreProperties.class)) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.findNameForSerialization(a);
    }
}

public class TestMain  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.setMyProperty("this is for test");
        try {
            String json = new ObjectMapper()
                    .setAnnotationIntrospector(new TestCustomIntrospector1())
                    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

another Introspector :

```
public class TestCustomIntrospector2 extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public boolean isAnnotationBundle(Annotation ann) {
        if (ann.annotationType() == JsonIgnoreProperties.class) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.isAnnotationBundle(ann);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
        JsonIgnoreProperties ignoreProperties = m.getAnnotation(JsonIgnoreProperties.class);
        if (ignoreProperties != null) {
            return ignoreProperties.ignoreUnknown();
        }
        return super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);
    }
}

public class TestMain  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.setMyProperty("this is for test");
        try {
            String json = new ObjectMapper()
                    .setAnnotationIntrospector(new TestCustomIntrospector2())
                    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I want following result:

```
{
  "myProperty": "this is for test"
}
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCustomIntrospector2 :

```
public class TestCustomIntrospector2 extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

        @Override
        public JsonIgnoreProperties.Value findPropertyIgnoralByName(MapperConfig<?> config, Annotated a){
            return JsonIgnoreProperties.Value.empty();
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi DingHao
thank for your answer. you resolve my problem, thank you very match.

Answer (score 1):

You are making your property available for deserialization (json to object) but not for serialization (object to json) by using:

```
allowSetters=true
```

If you want to be able to convert your object to json, you want to serialize that object, and then you should use allowGetters=true instead:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"myProperty"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Test {
    private String myProperty;

    // getter and setter 
}
```

And for improved readability:

```
public class Test {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters = true)
    private String myProperty;

    // getter and setter 
}
```

If you want to serialize and deserialize you should get rid of the annotation.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I know your solution Noah and I wouldn't change code and business for writing test.